# Datetime: Calcul Hours in days

Tags: scala, datetime

I have 3 scala functions, working well, I have an errors just in the function

I did another function equals: compute the number of hours between 2 dates by calling the 3 functions above: toEnd, ToStart, jourOuvree.
I wrote all the function in a scala Object. But when I run the function equals, it gives me an errors, this following:

```
                                     ^
```

I should use the function and apply it on my dataframe to compute the number of hours between 2 dates.

I'm not excellent in java.time API.
Someone can help me please to resolve these errors ?

Comment: can you provide signatures for `jourOuvree`, `toEnd` and `toStart`?

Comment: you mean by signaturethere codes ? I can edit my question if want ?

Comment: yes I meant codes of the functions

Comment: I edited my question from begin, I hope that is clear.
I'm sorry because the code is a bit long.
I'm looking how resolve the function equals to call the other three function (toEnd, ToStart and jourouvree) because I should apply it on my dataframe after.
Thank you very much

Comment: Your code does many things that make no sense. Here's one: this signature `jourOuvree(String,String):Unit` means that the method doesn't return anything (`Unit`). Therefore this `toEnd(LocalTime.of(d1))+jourOuvree(...` is impossible. You can't add `Unit` to a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your solution. See comments inline.

```
import java.time._
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Demo extends App {

  val start = LocalTime.of(9, 0)
  val midEnd = LocalTime.of(13, 0)
  val midStart = LocalTime.of(14, 0)
  val end = LocalTime.of(18, 0)
  val firstHalf = start.until(midEnd, ChronoUnit.MILLIS).millis
  val secondHalf = midStart.until(end, ChronoUnit.MILLIS).millis

  implicit class formatter(d: FiniteDuration) {
    def withMinutes = {
      val l = d.toMinutes
      s"${l / 60}:${l % 60}"
    }

    def withSeconds = s"${d.toHours}:${d.toMinutes % 60}:${d.toSeconds % 60}"
  }

  // check if day is working. Could be easily adjusted to check not only weekend but holidays as well
  def isWorkingDay(d: LocalDate) = !Set(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY).contains(d.getDayOfWeek)
  // check if current day is working day and if not switch to next start of day/previous end of day
  // depending on ask parameter
  @tailrec
  def adjust(t: LocalDateTime, asc: Boolean = true): LocalDateTime = {
    if (!isWorkingDay(t.toLocalDate) && asc) adjust(t.toLocalDate.plusDays(1).atTime(start), asc)
    else if (!isWorkingDay(t.toLocalDate) && !asc) adjust(t.toLocalDate.minusDays(1).atTime(end), asc)
    else t
  }

  def toEnd(t: LocalTime) = {
    if (t.isBefore(start)) firstHalf + secondHalf
    else if (t.isBefore(midEnd)) t.until(midEnd, ChronoUnit.MILLIS).millis + secondHalf
    else if (t.isBefore(midStart)) secondHalf
    else if (t.isBefore(end)) t.until(end, ChronoUnit.MILLIS).millis
    else 0.hours
  }


  def toStart(t: LocalTime) = {
    if (t.isBefore(start)) 0.hours
    else if (t.isBefore(midEnd)) start.until(t, ChronoUnit.MILLIS).millis
    else if (t.isBefore(midStart)) firstHalf
    else if (t.isBefore(end)) firstHalf + midStart.until(t, ChronoUnit.MILLIS).millis
    else firstHalf + secondHalf
  }

  // count amount of working days between two dates.
  // if dates are the same - means 0 days
  def jourOuvree(d1: LocalDate, d2: LocalDate): Int = {
    @tailrec
    def count(n: LocalDate, acc: Int): Int = {
      if (n.isEqual(d2) || n.isAfter(d2)) acc
      else if (!isWorkingDay(n)) count(n.plusDays(1), acc)
      else count(n.plusDays(1), acc + 1)
    }

    count(d1, 0)
  }

  // evaluate duration of working time between to date/times
  // take into account that start/end could be non-working and
  // adjust
  def toEquals(rd1: LocalDateTime, rd2: LocalDateTime) = {
    val d1 = adjust(rd1)
    val d2 = adjust(rd2, asc = false)
    // if we are in the same day ==> I should compute just a difference between hours
    if (d1.isAfter(d2)) 0.hours
    else if (d1.toLocalDate.isEqual(d2.toLocalDate)) {
      toEnd(d1.toLocalTime) - toEnd(d2.toLocalTime)
    }
    else {
      toEnd(d1.toLocalTime) + jourOuvree(d1.toLocalDate.plusDays(1), d2.toLocalDate.minusDays(1)) * 8.hours + toStart(d2.toLocalTime)
    }
  }

  val thursdayStart = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 1).atTime(start)
  val thursdayEnd = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 1).atTime(end)
  val fridayStart = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 2).atTime(start)
  val fridayEnd = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 2).atTime(end)
  val saturdayStart = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 3).atTime(start)
  val saturdayEnd = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 3).atTime(end)
  val sundayStart = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 4).atTime(start)
  val sundayEnd = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 4).atTime(end)
  val mondayStart = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 5).atTime(start)
  val mondayEnd = LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 6).atTime(end)
  println(toEquals(thursdayStart, sundayStart).withSeconds)
  println(toEquals(thursdayStart, saturdayStart).withSeconds)
  println(toEquals(thursdayStart, mondayStart).withSeconds)
  println(toEquals(thursdayStart, mondayEnd).withSeconds)
  println(toEquals(thursdayStart, thursdayEnd).withSeconds)

  // formatter to use to parse string input
  import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
  val DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  println(toEquals(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-03-01 11:22:33", DATE_TIME_FORMATTER), LocalDateTime.parse("2018-03-02 11:22:33", DATE_TIME_FORMATTER)).withSeconds)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have this error, when it find LocalDate or LocalTime or LocalDateTime, it display this error:  error: reference to LocalDate is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import java.time._
and import org.joda.time._

I added for each one an import: 
import org.joda.time.{LocalTime => MessagesLocalTime}
import java.time.{LocalTime => MessagesLocalTime}
but it does not resolve the error

Comment: I do not use joda.time in my solution. You should also use either java.time or joda.time, but not mix. They provide equivalent functionality, at joda site using of java.time is recommended.

Comment: Excuse me for this disturb,yes you have the right I should use joda or java.
Then, I running the Object Demo, it compile well, thank you, but I tried to run the function toEquals to verify by introducing 2 date like in the exemple: toEquals("2018-03-23 12:44:24","2018-03-28 15:45:46")
it display :
toEquals("2018-03-23 12:44:24","2018-03-28 15:45:46")
<console>:137: error: not found: value toEquals
       toEquals("2018-03-23 12:44:24","2018-03-28 15:45:46")
How can run it, to verify because I should apply a function after on 2 field LocalDateTime(start_date, finish_date) in my Dataframe.

Comment: Added formatter and example with string dates input

Comment: I'm very sorry, I can't understand how can I run the function.
I did toEquals(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-03-01 11:22:33", DATE_TIME_FORMATTER), LocalDateTime.parse("2018-03-02 11:22:33", DATE_TIME_FORMATTER)).withSeconds,
I did also toEquals("2018-03-23 12:24:44","2018-04-03 10:22:44") but always it display an error.
Please can you give me an example how can I run it by introducing 2 dates.
Thank you

Comment: Did you copy also `DATE_TIME_FORMATTER` from my code snippet? Is it defined in same scope as `toEquals` function (so available for usage)?

Comment: DATE_TIME_FORMATTER I defined it in the same scope of toEquals, but I added the println(....) outside toEquals.
It dispaly:  error: not found: value DATE_TIME_FORMATTER

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the problem. If `toEquals` is available in `println` it is either imported individually, or with wildcard. If individually, you need to import `DATE_TIME_FORMATTER` as well to access it in `println` outside `object`

Comment: I asked a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646232/datetime-import-library-scala?noredirect=1#comment86303184_49646232  : it's your solution, the object compile well, but when I run it, it dispaly an errors, can you help me please.

Comment: Can you give me an answer for my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804517/sparkcontext-in-sparksession/49804628#49804628   Thank you very much

Comment: @vero I cannot help you with spark-specific, since I did not work with spark, only scala specific querions, sorry..