# Build a SparkSession

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have a spark as interpreter in Zeppelin.
I'm using a Spark2.0, I built a Session: Create

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 3):

In general you should not initialize `SparkSession` nor `SparkContext` in Zeppelin. Zeppelin notebooks are configured to create session for you, and their correct behavior depends on using provided objects.

Initializing your `SparkSession` will break core Zeppelin functionalities, and multiple `SparkContexts` will break things completely in the worst case scenario.

> Is set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts to False is best to do a tests ?

You should never use `spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts` - it not supported, and doesn't guarantee correct results.